# TCPDF server sent different file name

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I tried to re-organize the TCPDF directories but every time I end up with lots of problem so I decided to stick with default one so my php file is

```
xxx.net/pdfgen/lib/examples/index.php
```

at the end of my code I have the following lines to save the generated file into the server as well

```
global $filetitle ; $filetitle = rand(0,9999);
$pdf->Output($filetitle, 'I');
$pdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../'.$filetitle.'.pdf', 'F');
```

if I run the file at this location, all is fine, but considring the long and ugly path, I decided to include it in another php file in upper directory

```
xxx.net/pdfgen/index.php
include('lib/examples/index.php');
```

if I open the new file I end up with a message saying

> server has sent different file name, do you want to accept it or not and that file indicates the function "rand" has re run again and generated new numbers and at the end two files are generated each time.

## Any idea how that could happen?

Comment: hi, definetly you need to store the generated pdf in server?

Answer (score 0):

after trial and error, it worked by replacing those lines

```
$pdf->Output($filetitle, 'I'); //output file to inline browser
$pdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../'.$filetitle.'.pdf', 'F');   //save to server
```

with (combine both actions)

```
$pdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../genpdf/'.$filetitle.'.pdf', 'FI');   // F:save to server & I: show in inline browser
```